# How do I make JavaScript (jQuery) code leaner?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the simple code below that is like tabs.

Code:

```js
$(".tab-1").click(function(){
    $(".content div").removeClass("active")
    $(".content .content-1").addClass("active")
    $(".tabs span").removeClass("active-tab")
    $(this).addClass("active-tab")
})

$(".tab-2").click(function(){
    $(".content div").removeClass("active")
    $(".content .content-2").addClass("active")
    $(".tabs span").removeClass("active-tab")
    $(this).addClass("active-tab")
})

$(".tab-3").click(function(){
    $(".content div").removeClass("active")
    $(".content .content-3").addClass("active")
    $(".tabs span").removeClass("active-tab")
    $(this).addClass("active-tab")
})
```

```css
.tabs span {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs .active-tab {
    background: #ccc;
    color: black;
}

.content div {
    display: none;
}

.content .active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
    <div class="tabs">
      <span class="tab-1 active-tab">Tab 1</span>
      <span class="tab-2">Tab 2</span>
      <span class="tab-3">Tab 3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content-1 active">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse at omnis magni, minus facilis vitae ipsum. THIS IS TAB 1.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content-2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse at omnis magni, minus facilis vitae ipsum. THIS IS TAB 2.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content-3">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse at omnis magni, minus facilis vitae ipsum. THIS IS TAB 3.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
```

As you can see it's pretty simple. You click on the different tabs and based on that the content changes nothing too complicated and it works. The problem is that the JS is way too repetitive and also if there were 5-6-7 elements it would be a pain if I decide that I want to change something because I'd have to go through each element individually. My question is how to do I make the code leaner and how can I add more elements without having to make changes to the JS?

Comment: Best advice I can give, stop using jquery. Long term solution.

Comment: [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can omit the specific tab-1 and content-1 classes and use `.index()`:

```js
$(".tabs span").click(function(){
    $(".content div").removeClass("active")
                     .eq($(this).index()).addClass("active");
    $(".tabs span").removeClass("active-tab");
    $(this).addClass("active-tab");
})
```

```css
.tabs span {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs .active-tab {
    background: #ccc;
    color: black;
}

.content div {
    display: none;
}

.content .active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
    <div class="tabs">
      <span class="active-tab">Tab 1</span>
      <span>Tab 2</span>
      <span>Tab 3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="active">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse at omnis magni, minus facilis vitae ipsum. THIS IS TAB 1.</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse at omnis magni, minus facilis vitae ipsum. THIS IS TAB 2.</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse at omnis magni, minus facilis vitae ipsum. THIS IS TAB 3.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The methodology you can use to clean this code up is called the ['Dont' Repeat Yourself' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), or DRY.

To achieve it in this case you can use the `this` keyword to refer to the element which raised the `click` event. From there you can traverse the DOM to find the related elements, or use the `index()` of the tab to find the related content, and amend them without having to select them directly. Try this:

```js
let $tabs = $('.tabs > .tab');
let $content = $('.content-container > .content');

$(".tab").click(function() {
  $tabs.removeClass('active');
  let $tab = $(this).addClass('active');
  $content.removeClass('active').eq($tab.index()).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.tabs > .tab {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs .active {
  background: #ccc;
  color: black;
}

.content-container .content {
  display: none;
}

.content-container .content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <span class="tab active">Tab 1</span>
  <span class="tab">Tab 2</span>
  <span class="tab">Tab 3</span>
</div>
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="content active">
    <p>THIS IS TAB 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse at omnis magni, minus facilis vitae ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>THIS IS TAB 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse at omnis magni, minus facilis vitae ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>THIS IS TAB 3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse at omnis magni, minus facilis vitae ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this :

```js
$('.tabs > span').on('click', function(){
  let ind = $(this).index();
  $('.content > div').removeClass('active').eq(ind).addClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active-tab').siblings().removeClass('active-tab');
});
```

```css
.tabs span {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs .active-tab {
  background: #ccc;
  color: black;
}

.content div {
  display: none;
}

.content .active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<div class="tabs">
  <span class="tab-1 active-tab">Tab 1</span>
  <span class="tab-2">Tab 2</span>
  <span class="tab-3">Tab 3</span>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-1 active">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse at omnis magni, minus facilis vitae ipsum. THIS IS TAB 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content-2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse at omnis magni, minus facilis vitae ipsum. THIS IS TAB 2.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content-3">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse at omnis magni, minus facilis vitae ipsum. THIS IS TAB 3.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the index of the item you clicked on and use that to change the class of the content with the same index. Be aware that the order of HTML needs to follow the order of the tabs.

```js
$(".tab").click(function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    
    $(".content").removeClass("active")
    $(".content:eq("+index+")").addClass("active")
    
    $(".tabs span").removeClass("active-tab")
    $(this).addClass("active-tab")
   
})
```

```css
.tabs span {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs .active-tab {
    background: #ccc;
    color: black;
}

.content-wrapper div {
    display: none;
}

.content-wrapper .active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <span class="tab active-tab">Tab 1</span>
  <span class="tab">Tab 2</span>
  <span class="tab">Tab 3</span>
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="content active">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse at omnis magni, minus facilis vitae ipsum. THIS IS TAB 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse at omnis magni, minus facilis vitae ipsum. THIS IS TAB 2.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse at omnis magni, minus facilis vitae ipsum. THIS IS TAB 3.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, you could add "data-index" attribute to your tabs toggler spans (matching them with desired tabs "content-$index" classes, or better yet, ids), so you can pass it to js and easily toggle between tabs. Something like this:

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <span class="tab-1 active-tab" data-index="1">Tab 1</span>
  <span class="tab-2" data-index="2">Tab 2</span>
  <span class="tab-3" data-index="3">Tab 3</span>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-1 active" id="content-1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse at omnis magni, minus facilis vitae ipsum. THIS IS TAB 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content-2" id="content-2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse at omnis magni, minus facilis vitae ipsum. THIS IS TAB 2.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content-3" id="content-3">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse at omnis magni, minus facilis vitae ipsum. THIS IS TAB 3.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

```js
(function($) {
  const contDiv = $('.content-div');
  const tabsSpan = $('.tabs span');

  /**
   * getContentEl
   * @param index
   * @return {jQuery|HTMLElement}
   */
  function getContentEl(index) {
    return $('#content-' + index);
  }

  /**
   * toggleTab
   * @param e
   * @return {boolean}
   */
  function toggleTab(e) {
    const el = $(e.currentTarget);
    const index = el.attr('data-index');

    getContentEl(index).addClass('active');
    contDiv.removeClass('active');
    tabsSpan.removeClass('active-tab');
    el.addClass('active-tab');

    return true;
  }

  tabsSpan.on('click', toggleTab);
})(jQuery);
```